# KeyError while retrieving random parameter from dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, random

So currently im working on a black jack game where cards are put in a dictionary and each starting deck has a random card taken from the dictionary but when i execute the code i get a keyerror

code

```
# Black Jack
import random
from art import logo
print(logo)
cards = {
    "ace": [1, 11],
    "one": 1,
    'two': 2,
    'three': 3,
    "four": 4,
    "Five": 5,
    "six": 6,
    'seven': 7,
    'eight': 8,
    'nine': 9,
    "king": 10,
    "queen": 10,
    "jack": 10,
    "ten": 10
}

user_deck = []
computer_deck = []
user_deck.append(random.choice(cards))
computer_deck.append(random.choice(cards))
print(f"{computer_deck} \n {user_deck}" )
```

Comment: random.choice needs a list, not a dict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`random.choice(seq)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) does

> Return a random element from the non-empty sequence *seq*.

and you give it `dict` which is not [sequence](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq), you need first to convert `keys` of said `dict` into sequence, for example `tuple` that is replace

```
user_deck.append(random.choice(cards))
computer_deck.append(random.choice(cards))
```

using

```
user_deck.append(random.choice(tuple(cards.keys())))
computer_deck.append(random.choice(tuple(cards.keys())))
```

Comment: Based on the docs you should use random.choice(list(dict))

Comment: @OmOWalker where exactly in docs it does devise such way for dealing with keys of dict for `random.choice`?

Answer (score 0):

Consider doing it in the following way:

```
user_deck.append(random.choice(tuple(cards.keys())))
computer_deck.append(random.choice(tuple(cards.keys())))
```

The problem is random.choice() accepts seq which has to support `__getitem__()` and `__len__()` methods, it should be list or tuple, not set or dict which you passed.